# How to share articles on Facebook using Facebook api with article thumbnail in the post?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, express

I have a React-node based blog (https://www.edvicer.com/blog). I want to share the articles on Facebook using Facebook api like Medium does (https://medium.com/s/user-friendly/simple-is-bad-1381784fd679) with thumbnail of the article in the post.

I have tried using Facebook Share dialog plugin but firstly the UI of the shared post is not like Medium has with full-sized picture in the post. And secondly, Facebook Share Dialog plugin takes image from the meta tags of the website.

In order to use different meta tags for different article, I have tried using react-meta-tags (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-meta-tags) but it changes meta tags after rendering the page which is not detected by Facebook debugger and I don't see the tags I set in the shared post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to implement this without server-side rendering. The crawler needs to see the image. Try using facebook debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ see if it helps.

Comment: Thank you. I rendered my meta tags from the server for each route separately. I followed exactly what was written here: https://www.kapwing.com/blog/how-to-add-dynamic-meta-tags-server-side-with-create-react-app/ and it worked.